# Converting zip+4 to zip python

Tags: pandas, regex, dataframe, replace, zipcode

I am looking to convert zip+4 codes into zip codes in a pandas dataframe. I want it to identify that a zip 4 code exists and keep just the first 5 digits. I effectively want to do the below code (although this doesn't work in this format):

```
df.replace('^(\d{5}-?\d{4})', group(1), regex=True)
```

The following code does the same procedure for a list, I'm looking to do the same thing in the dataframe.

```
my_input = ['01234-5678', '012345678', '01234', 'A1A 1A1', 'A1A1A1']
expression = re.compile(r'^(\d{5})-?(\d{4})?$')

my_output = []
for string in my_input: 
    if m := re.match(expression, string): 
        my_output.append(re.match(expression, string).group(1)) 
    else: 
        my_output.append(string)
```

Comment: Why do you use `group(0)`, do you understand what it means? You want `df.replace(r'^(\d{5})-\d{4}$', group(1), regex=True)`

Comment: Yeah, I made a coding mistake there, I meant to write group(1) as in the string regex code. I have replaced the top one to be group(1). That still doesn't work though, althoughthe code below has fixed it. It needs to be '\1' instead of 'group(1)'

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
df = df.replace(r'^(\d{5})-?\d{4}$', r'\1', regex=True)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uIQZIa/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d{5})` - Group 1 (`\1`): five digits
- `-?` - an optional `-`
- `\d{4}` - any four digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it would be a simple solution. I understood the regex as I wrote it, just not how to apply it to the dataframe, but useful information for others looking at this question. I just needed to know how to reference the first group.